# How to find/run RefreshAll?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheet1.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

This window pops up

[image]

> Compile error:
> Method or data member not found

It directs me to the RefreshAll function.

When I was writing the line, after the fullstop, the drop down list didn't show the RefreshAll function.

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Answer (score 1):

`RefreshAll` is the method for `Workbook` object. So, you cannot use with `Worksheet` object. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall

Answer (score 0):

As @Adisak said, `RefreshAll` is a method of `Workbook` object, not `Worksheet` object.

So, you need to do one of the following:

1: Refresh all for the whole workbook.

`ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`

2: Loop through the objects you want to refresh within the sheet and refresh them one by one. (As mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/474479da-c2b0-46fd-b56f-c86fe56a3ed4/refresh-all-pivots-in-a-worksheet-using-vba) for pivot tables)

```
Sub RefreshPT()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Set wsh = Sheet1
    For Each pvt In wsh.PivotTables
        pvt.RefreshTable
    Next pvt
End Sub
```